# Gracefully terminate threadpool tasks dispatched by QueueUserWorkItem()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I'm using `QueueUserWorkItem()` to fetch data from a `NetStream` , if such available, on an "autopilot"  paradigm. I Prefer not to manage my own thread for this task, due to few reasons, one of which is the fact that there many parallel calls.

Upon application termination (**not** necessarily *Process* termination) I'd wish to terminate those work items gracefully. that is, acknowledging the threads that the application is shutting down , and letting them an opportunity to fold peacefully.

How should that be done?

Comment: Look into [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997364(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: That will do! BTW, as it was only introduced in `.NET4` , what would you recommend for `.NET` < 4  ?

Comment: Prior to .NET 4.0, I would use [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). Create a `ManualResetEvent` and have the threads periodically do a `WaitOne(0)` on it to see if it's been set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .NET 4.0 and later, use [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997364%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Prior to .NET 4.0, use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

For some simple examples, see my blog, [Polling for cancellation](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/07/polling-for-cancellation/).